# Android set Layout align left and center vertical programmatically

Tags: java, android

I want to have `arrowview` overlap on `homeview` in center vertical left. I have tried to do so using couple of `views` but didn't work. It shows me overlap but on left top corner instead of left center vertical. Please help me.

```
private RelativeLayout makeContentView1() {
    RelativeLayout arrowView = new RelativeLayout(this);
    arrowView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.image);
    //RelativeLayout.LayoutParams relativeParams = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams)arrowView.getLayoutParams();
    //relativeParams.setMargins(0, 80, 0, 0);
    //arrowView.setLayoutParams(relativeParams);
    arrowView.setGravity(RelativeLayout.CENTER_VERTICAL | RelativeLayout.ALIGN_LEFT);
    return arrowView;

}

public void makeLayout() {
    homeView = new RelativeLayout(this);
    LayoutParams lp = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

    homeView.setLayoutParams(lp);

    bodyView = this.makeBodyView();
    arrowView = this.makeContentView1(300,300);

    homeView.addView(bodyView);
    homeView.addView(arrowView);

    return homeView;

}
```

Comment: In a RelativeLayout it overlaps smaller size layout onto larger Layout. Then you can set gravity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achive your task by using a single `RelativeLayout`with applying rules on it,
Use the below code to achive this,

```
private RelativeLayout makeContentView1() {
    RelativeLayout arrowView = new RelativeLayout(this);
    arrowView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.image);


    return arrowView;
}

public void makeLayout() {
    homeView = new RelativeLayout(this);
    LayoutParams lp = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);

    homeView.setLayoutParams(lp);

    bodyView = this.makeBodyView();
    arrowView = this.makeContentView1(300,300);

    homeView.addView(bodyView);
    homeView.addView(arrowView);

    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams relativeParams =       (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams)arrowView.getLayoutParams();
    relativeParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_VERTICAL);
    arrowView.setLayoutParams(relativeParams);
return homeView;

}
```

Comment: Thanks but it throws error:             Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.RelativeLayout$LayoutParams.addRule(int)' on a null object reference

Comment: On that time `relativeParams `is null thats it is throwing null pointer...!